# how to get href and text content by html Content

Tags: php, html-content-extraction

I am want to get content and url including all other td data.

my code:

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        "http" => array(
            "header" => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
        )
    )
);

$htmlContent = file_get_contents("https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db", false, $context);
    
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($htmlContent);

$FirstdTable = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(0);


$Header = $FirstdTable->getElementsByTagName('th');
$Detail = $FirstdTable->getElementsByTagName('td');

//#Get header name of the table
foreach($Header as $NodeHeader) 
{
    $aDataTableHeaderHTML[] = trim($NodeHeader->textContent);
}

//#Get row data/detail table without header name as key
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
foreach($Detail as $sNodeDetail)
{
   
    $aDataTableDetailHTML[$j][] = trim($sNodeDetail->textContent);
    $i = $i + 1;
    $j = $i % count($aDataTableHeaderHTML) == 0 ? $j + 1 : $j;
}
```

current output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => .aaa
            [1] => generic
            [2] => American Automobile Association, Inc.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => .aarp
            [1] => generic
            [2] => AARP
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => .abarth
            [1] => generic
            [2] => Fiat Chrysler Automobiles N.V.
        )
}
```

here i am want as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => .aaa
            [1] => generic
            [2] => American Automobile Association, Inc.
            [3] => https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/aaa.html
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => .aarp
            [1] => generic
            [2] => AARP
            [3] => https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/aarp.html
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => .abarth
            [1] => generic
            [2] => Fiat Chrysler Automobiles N.V.
            [3] => https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/abarth.html
        )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you're just getting all the text content within all `<td>`'s. And it's not going to include the link inside the anchor tags. To do so, you'll need to dig deeper into the `<td>`.

Here's one way to do it using `xpath`:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($DOM);
$base = 'https://www.iana.org/';
foreach($Detail as $sNodeDetail)
{
    $aDataTableDetailHTML[$j][] = trim($sNodeDetail->textContent);
    if ($link = $xpath->evaluate("string(./span[contains(@class, 'domain')]/a/@href)", $sNodeDetail)) {
        $aDataTableDetailHTML[$j][] = "{$base}{$link}";
    }
    $i = $i + 1;
    $j = $i % count($aDataTableHeaderHTML) == 0 ? $j + 1 : $j;
}
```

Basically the query just extract the `href` value if the current `<td>` in the iteration has `<span class="domain tld"><a href="xxxx">xxx</a></span>` and get the `href` value.

Another way is to iterate each `<tr>` instead of each `<td>`:

```
$aDataTableDetailHTML = [];
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($htmlContent);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($DOM);
$base = 'https://www.iana.org/';
foreach($xpath->query('//table[@id="tld-table"]/tbody/tr') as $row) {
    $domain = trim($xpath->evaluate("string(./td[1])", $row));
    $type = $xpath->evaluate("string(./td[2])", $row);
    $tld_manager = $xpath->evaluate("string(./td[3])", $row);
    $url = $xpath->evaluate("string(./td[1]/span/a/@href)", $row);
    $aDataTableDetailHTML[] = [$domain, $type, $tld_manager, "{$base}{$url}"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its working but if i need to get content including html elements inside td[1] ex. <td><a href="#test">test</a><td> output should be: <a href="#test">test</a>